# Hashes don't seem to match even though created with the same params

Tags: solidity, hash, keccak

I have a function in Solidity that is supposed to check if the `recovery hash` committed by the Email recovery service matches the hash generated through the token and nonce sent by the user (He receives this from his email). Here's how the code looks:

```
///@dev Called by the email service which commits the recovery hash
function commitRecoveryHash(bytes32 recoveryHash) external onlyEmailVerificationService {
        emailVerificationHash = recoveryHash;
    }
```

Here's how the email recovery service generates the recovery hash

```
 address emailService = address(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720); 
    string userEmail = "shiven@gmail.com";
    uint64 nonce = 38;
    

vm.startPrank(emailService);
        bytes memory recoveryToken = (abi.encodePacked(userEmail, emailService));
        emit EmailServiceGeneratingHashUsing(recoveryToken, nonce);
    
        bytes32 emailVerificationHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(recoveryToken, nonce));

        accountRecovery.commitRecoveryHash(emailVerificationHash);
        vm.stopPrank();
```

Now I have a test that calls the function to check if the recovery hashes match.

```
 address emailService = address(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720); // TODO: To be updated with the wallet address of the actual email
    string userEmail = "shiven@gmail.com";
    uint64 nonce = 38;
    

 function testUserVerification() external {
        bytes memory recoveryToken = abi.encodePacked(userEmail, emailService);
        // creating a new Embedded wallet for the user
        address newWallet = makeAddr("newWallet");

        // Act/ Assert
        vm.prank(newWallet); // using the new wallet to send recovery req.
        vm.expectEmit();
        emit AccountRecoveryRequestCreated();
        accountRecovery.verifyUserAsOwnerOfTheAccount(userEmail, recoveryToken, nonce);
    }
```

Here's the test calling the `verifyUserAsOwnerOfTheAccount()` using the same recovery token, email, and nonce:

```
 function verifyUserAsOwnerOfTheAccount(
        string memory email,
        bytes calldata token,
        uint256 nonce
    ) internal returns (bool) {
       
        ///@dev Hashing strings to compare them.
        emit AboutToGenerateHashUsing(token, nonce);

        bytes32 generatedEmailVerificationHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token, nonce));
        emit RecoveryHash(emailVerificationHash);
        emit GeneratedHash(generatedEmailVerificationHash);

        console.log("Do the email hash match:", (generatedEmailVerificationHash == emailVerificationHash));

        if (generatedEmailVerificationHash != emailVerificationHash) {
            revert EmailVerificationFailed();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Please note the events `EmailServiceGeneratingHashUsing` & `AboutToGenerateHashUsing` prove that the same params went into creating the hashes and the same `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(recoveryToken, nonce))` method was used to create the hashes, but still the hashes don't match. Here are the logs:

```
 VM::stopPrank() 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ emit EmailServiceGeneratingHashUsing(token: 0x73686976656e40676d61696c2e636f6da0ee7a142d267c1f36714e4a8f75612f20a79720, nonce: 38)
    ├─ [22408] AccountRecovery::commitRecoveryHash(0x271f87acd2085f2e203d8d983e89f336274e0c2028ebc7340703b3b141b0b6dc) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::stopPrank() 
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← ()

  [32967] AccountRecoveryTest::testRecoveryRequestGeneration() 
    ├─ [0] VM::addr(<pk>) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← newWallet: [0xBc1Ce00634302d0DfDF22B8C2b8Dc81011bCA560]
    ├─ [0] VM::label(newWallet: [0xBc1Ce00634302d0DfDF22B8C2b8Dc81011bCA560], newWallet) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::prank(newWallet: [0xBc1Ce00634302d0DfDF22B8C2b8Dc81011bCA560]) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::expectEmit() 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ emit AccountRecoveryRequestCreated()
    ├─ [14330] AccountRecovery::verifyUserAsOwnerOfTheAccount(shiven@gmail.com, 0x73686976656e40676d61696c2e636f6da0ee7a142d267c1f36714e4a8f75612f20a79720, 38) 
    │   ├─ emit AboutToGenerateHashUsing(receivedToken: 0x73686976656e40676d61696c2e636f6da0ee7a142d267c1f36714e4a8f75612f20a79720, nonce: 38)
    │   ├─ emit RecoveryHash(recoveryHash: 0x271f87acd2085f2e203d8d983e89f336274e0c2028ebc7340703b3b141b0b6dc)
    │   ├─ emit GeneratedHash(generatedHash: 0x7c3438dd181130e624805b50265942f829f784fc1720b189431743713d7e826c)
    │   ├─ [0] console::log(Do the email hash match:, false) [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   └─ ← "EmailVerificationFailed()"
    └─ ← "Log != expected log"
```

I'm not able to figure out why the `emailVerificationHash` & `generatedEmailVerificationHash` don't match.

```
emit RecoveryHash(recoveryHash: 0x271f87acd2085f2e203d8d983e89f336274e0c2028ebc7340703b3b141b0b6dc)
emit GeneratedHash(generatedHash: 0x7c3438dd181130e624805b50265942f829f784fc1720b189431743713d7e826c)
```

Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash was being created using a `uint64 nonce` in the test file whereas in the contract it was generated using `uint256 nonce`. Since the data type of `nonce` was different, the hashes were different.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I created the `emailVerificationHash` in the contract's `commitRecoveryHash(...)` instead of sending the hash from the test suite directly.

Here's how the `commitRecoveryHash()` is modified:

```
function commitRecoveryHash(
        bytes calldata recoveryToken,
        uint256 recoveryTokenNonce
    ) external onlyEmailVerificationService {
        emailVerificationHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(recoveryToken, recoveryTokenNonce)); // generating the hash instead of receiving it
    }
```

You will notice how the function signature has changed. Instead of receiving the `bytes32 recoveryHash` the `commitRecoveryHash(..)` will now receive `bytes calldata recoveryToken, uint256 recoveryTokenNonce` and will generate the `recoveryHash` in the contract itself.

Here's how the test setup function will look:

```
 // commiting the recovery params to create email verification hash (representing the email recovery service)
        vm.startPrank(emailService);
        emit EmailServiceGeneratingHashUsing(recoveryToken, nonce);

        accountRecovery.commitRecoveryHash(recoveryToken, nonce); // sending hash generation params instead of the hash itself
        vm.stopPrank();
```

With the `emailRecoveryHash` being produced in the contract itself the test passes.

I still don't understand why Foundry is resulting in different hashes in the test file vs the contract, even when using exactly the same params? I even checked by freezing the solidity versions of both the contract and test file to 0.8.18, but still, different hashes were produced. Does anyone know why this could be happening?